# Elasticsearch 2.3 on Debian

Tags: elasticsearch

we've recently upgraded from 1.4 to 2.3 and we can't seem to get our 1.4 indexes working. Anyone dealt with this issue?

We've tried updating the config files, copying the data to a "2.3" folder and ES just keeps crashing.

This is where our data is:
/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_cognac

But updating the config file just add another '/elasticsearch' directory so it looks like this:

/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_cognac/elasticsearch

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if your 1.4 mappings are compatible with 2.3 before attempting the migration.

There is a specific plugin, called [migration](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-migration), that you need to install in your 1.4 cluster in order to get some insights whether you need to make some changes first (it looks like you do) or not.

Go to your 1.4 installation folder, and install the plugin

```
./bin/plugin -i elastic/elasticsearch-migration
```

Then start your ES and go to http://localhost:9200/_plugin/migration

You'll get plenty of info about what you need to change before attempting a migration.

Comment: Is there any more info you need concerning this issue?